# Switch from Xubuntu to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu 22.04 and was looking to switch over to Kubuntu 22.04.
I like xubuntu - it's just time for a change.

Most searches come up with answers from a long time ago, but am i correct in the following steps?

sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop

install / upgrade - restart into kubuntu.

sudo apt remove xfce-desktop
sudo apt autoremove

should i use a *purge* command instead of remove?

any other tips appreciated.

thanks

Comment: It is much better to do a fresh install of Kubuntu. This way you may have lots of problems.

Comment: hi pilot6, is it really likely to cause problems? xfce is pretty light weight. i was considering fresh install but i've got it all dialed in so nicely atm...

Comment: You'll have both apps and settings. Not a lot of trouble, but some strangeness... `remove xubuntu-desktop` wont remove everything.